# Android associate class to top menu

Tags: android, class, menu

I'm begin to develop an android application. In my application I have a top menu with many option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_languages"
        android:title="@string/action_laguages"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
        android:title="@string/action_notification"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"/>

</menu>
```

I know how to create top menu and associate it to an activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.topmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I know how to execute code by menu action.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_languages:
                Intent languages = new Intent(this, TeamProject_Languages.class);
                this.startActivity(languages);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_notifications:
                if((item != null) && (item.isCheckable()) && (item.isChecked())){
                    item.setChecked(false);
                }else if((item != null) && (item.isCheckable()) && (!item.isChecked())){
                    item.setChecked(true);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent settings = new Intent(this, TeamProject_Settings.class);
                this.startActivity(settings);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

But I want to know if it's possible to associate a class to this menu. This to write the code juste one time and not in all activity in when I need to use it.
If it's possible anybody can say me how to do this ?
In the best case I juste want to only write the code which permit to associate the menu to the activity class.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. For those who want make the same thing this is my solution.
I create a java class with extends of "AppCompatActivity" and I had function which permit to create the menu as in a base activity.
Then activity in which I want my menu extends of my own class.

I hope this can help you and also you can understand my question and my solution.